# laravel 9 undefined variable $role

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i have try to do permisssion and role in laravel 9 but i have a error .
User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'secretword',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\Role')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
        if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
        abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Role model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

AdminController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('role:ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.home');
    }
}
```

SuperAdminController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SuperAdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('role:ROLE_SUPERADMIN');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('superadmin.home');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/superadmin', [App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdminController::class, 'index']);

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

app / Http / Middleware / CheckRole.php

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use Closure;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class CheckRole

{

    /**

     * Handle an incoming request.

     *

     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request

     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next

     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse

     */

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)

    {

        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {

            abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');

        }

        return $next($request);

    }

}
```

I try to do permissions and roles in laravel 9.And when i want to go /admin i have this error and show me this file i want to know how can i resolve this error for all good work?

Comment: you are directly trying to call $role variable in CheckRole class , but I cannot see anywhere you have passed or initialized this variable in this class.

Comment: @Ajit Hogade thanks for your help, i have edit my question with more code. Can you check and talk my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pass and accept the parameter of role, in middleware.

Your middleware

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string $role)
```

If you are using route for middleware then

```
Route::resource(...)->middleware('middlewareName:roleName');
```

If controller being used

```
$this->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class.':roleName')
```

To send argument to the middleware, use `:` after the middleware name. To send multiple argument, separate the arguments with `,`.

Comment: thanks for your help, i have edit my question with more code. Can you check and talk my error?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using Policy classes for this. Then you can simply use the `can` middleware.

More info here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#creating-policies

Your models basically would have their own policy classes per model, then you can fine tune exactly what users can do based on what their role is.

No need to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: i have do this but it's not resolve php artisan make:policy RolePolicy --model=Role

Comment: @xajetin what do you mean by it doesn't resolve?

Comment: in this time i have this error : php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder

   INFO  Seeding database.  


   Error 

  Class "Database\Seeders\User" not found

  at database/seeders/UserSeeder.php:17
     13▕      * @return void
     14▕      */
     15▕     public function run()
     16▕     {
  ➜  17▕         $user = User::find($user_id);
     18▕         $user->assignRole('Admin');
     19▕     }
     20▕ } `

`

Comment: check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73277380/laravel-9-401unauthorized/73277667#73277667 i need there help