# laravel 9 401unauthorized

Tags: php, laravel

database/migration/create_roles_table.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->string('name')->unique();
           $table->string('display_name')->nullable();
           $table->string('description')->nullable();
           $table->timestamps();
       });
       
   }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
   }
};
```

create_roles_user_table.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRoleUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('role_user');
    }
};
```

user migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('secretword');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

models User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'secretword',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Role::class)
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
        if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
        abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckRole
{
   /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    */
   public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string $role)
   {
       if (! $request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
           abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
       }
       return $next($request);
   }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/admin', [App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/superadmin', [App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdminController::class, 'index']);

Route::resource('posts', PostController::class);
```

Hello, I'm trying to make an admin panel so that only the admin can have access. I created a user account but I don't know how to change it to admin or super admin. I already have the ready view I wanted to know how I can make an admin user because I'm trying to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin it makes me
401
Unauthorized
how can I become an admin to be authorized to go to these pages?

Answer (score 0):

First run the command,

```
php artisan make:seeder UserSeeder
```

Then, go to database/seeders/UserSeeder.php and put the following code in run() method

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
$user->assignRole('Admin');
```

Then, run the following command

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder
```

Comment: i have this error in terminal `php artisan db:seed --class=UserSeeder

   INFO  Seeding database.  


   Error 

  Class "Database\Seeders\User" not found

  at database/seeders/UserSeeder.php:17
     13▕      * @return void
     14▕      */
     15▕     public function run()
     16▕     {
  ➜  17▕         $user = User::find($user_id);
     18▕         $user->assignRole('Admin');
     19▕     }
     20▕ }
     21▕ 

      +23 vendor frames 
  24  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
`

Comment: will you attach the pic of your UserSeeder.php , so I can help you out with the error?
This is my UserSeeder.php and it works fine
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $user = User::find(1);
        $user->assignRole('Super-Admin');
    }
}

Comment: i see i don't use package spatie for this

Comment: have you included the User model namespace at the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try `dd(auth()->user()->roles)` and see what it returns, check if there is the specified role. Also check `dd($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first())` and see what it returns.

Also I recommend to use the package: [Spaties's Laravel-permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction)

Comment: thanks for your help but i don't want use package